# Convert an input into a string and two floats

Tags: python, string, numbers, coordinates

I want to convert an input into a string and two numbers the user input will be something like "64 Union St Norwich NR2 2SL",52.624388,1.285323 it will always be separated by a "," and in that order.

```
    coordinates = input("Enter data")
    address, lat, long = map(float, coordinates.split(","))
```

Yes I know I put "float" into the code I am unsure what I need to put there to make address a string and lat and long a float. 
I have tried the below and it needs two arguments

```
    address, lat, long = map(coordinates.split(","))
```

Comment: You know there is an extra comma in your address right?

Comment: You just need to split off the last two items from the input string. Take a look at `str.rsplit`, and its `maxsplit` arg.

Comment: What's the problem? You `split` the input and convert the last two variables to `float`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are different ways of making this split work. One as already sugggsted is `rsplit`

```
address, lat, long = coordinates.split(",")
```

Note however that you cannot use `map` here because you have two different types of data; string and float. Attempting to convert the string to a float would produce an error. You can try this if you want a one liner.

```
address, lat, long = [float(a) if i > 0 else a for i, a in enumerate(coordinates.rsplit(',',2))]
```

on second, thoughts it's possible to use map, but with a lambda

```
map(lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == 0 else float(x[1]),enumerate(coordinates))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
string_split = coordinates.split(",")
address, lat, long = string_split[0], float(string_split[1]), float(string_split[2])
```